# Customize Time For Launch Screen

Tags: xcode, swift, launch

I am working with Xcode 7.2 and swift 2. I added a launch screen in the launch story board. However, when I run the app, the launch screen disappears quickly. Is there any way that I can customize the time for it?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can create a whole new ViewController to display a splash screen like:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    self.generateRandomSplashScreen()
    self.performSelector("removeSplashScreen", withObject: nil, afterDelay: <Your delay in seconds>)
    self.otherViewControllerLoad()
    // the other view controller
    self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()
    return true
}

func generateRandomSplashScreen() {
    splashScreenViewController = SplashScreenController(nibName: "SplashScreenController", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
    self.window.addSubview(self.splashScreenViewController.view!)
}

func removeSplashScreen() {
    splashScreenViewController.view!.removeFromSuperview()
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController

}
```